# Tableau rest api is giving error Unexpected Error

Tags: javascript, php, tableau-api

I am trying to embed tableau dashboard in my php website by requesting documents through local host tableau server.
I am embedding in iframe through javscript api by calling http request on IIS server but dashboard does not load correctly in IE only while loads correctly in all other browsers.
It gives following  error `Unexpected Error ... Unable to get property '   ' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Ajax requests are different in IE. A good start is to use a robust framework such as jQuery. A second is to show a minimal code snippet that we can use to reproduce the error

Comment: well viz object has it's own way to send request to url and to load dashboard not through jquery.

Comment: Well I can't help you without a minimal and reproducible code snippet